# Angular 4 array values are lost

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have a method which assigns an array returned from from a http request to another array. The issue is that it appears that after the method completes, the array with the new values becomes empty.

Method with http request.

```
loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(rowId: number) {
    this.bookingFullRowData[rowId] = [];
    this.bookingService.getAllBookingData().subscribe(res => {
      this.bookingFullRowData = <Booking[]>res[rowId];
      console.log('all booking data: ', this.bookingFullRowData, 'rowId: ', rowId);
      for (const item of this.bookingFullRowData) {
        const itemId = `${item['title']}-rowid-${item['rowid']}-proj-${item['proj']}`;
        this.bookingsForm.addControl(itemId, new FormControl(
          `${item['content']}`
        ));
      }
    });
  }
```

[image: data logged to the console]

Method which attempts to use the data from the updated array.

```
launchModal(element) {

    const elementId = (event.target as Element).id;
    const elementIdArray = String(elementId).split('-');
    this.currentRow = parseInt(elementIdArray[2], 10);
    this.loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(this.currentRow);
    console.log('the whole loaded dta:', this.bookingFullRowData, 'row: ', this.currentRow);

    this.modalService.createModal('#bookings-form', null, this.dialogOptions);
  }
```

The console.log just outputs an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the `getAllBookingData` method is asynchronous. That means that it issues a request but does not immediately get a response.

The function we pass into the subscribe method is basically a callback function that is executed when the response is returned.

That means that the code within

`this.bookingService.getAllBookingData().subscribe()` // <-- HERE

Is executed at some later point in time.

So all of the code after this line:

```
this.loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(this.currentRow);
// Any code below here!!
console.log('the whole loaded dta:', this.bookingFullRowData, 'row: ', this.currentRow);

this.modalService.createModal('#bookings-form', null, this.dialogOptions);
```

is executed **BEFORE** the function passed into the subscribe method.

So to solve your issue, you need to move *all* code that needs to execute after the data is retrieved within the callback function:

```
loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(rowId: number) {
    this.bookingFullRowData[rowId] = [];
    this.bookingService.getAllBookingData().subscribe(res => {
      this.bookingFullRowData = <Booking[]>res[rowId];
      console.log('all booking data: ', this.bookingFullRowData, 'rowId: ', rowId);
      for (const item of this.bookingFullRowData) {
        const itemId = `${item['title']}-rowid-${item['rowid']}-proj-${item['proj']}`;
        this.bookingsForm.addControl(itemId, new FormControl(
          `${item['content']}`
        ));
      }
      console.log('the whole loaded dta:', this.bookingFullRowData, 'row: ', this.currentRow);

      this.modalService.createModal('#bookings-form', null, this.dialogOptions);

    });
  }
```

As a side note, don't use `.toPromise` Stick with Observables.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not waiting. Notice the comments below:

```
// Launch async task in terms of subscribe
this.loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(this.currentRow);

// use loaded data *without waiting*
console.log('the whole loaded dta:', this.bookingFullRowData, 'row: ', this.currentRow);
```

You need to use the data *after* subscribe is called.

## More

Use `toPromise` and then chain with `then`. Docs : https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/utility/topromise.html

Answer (score 0):

As subscribe funciton is making an asynchronous call, you need to make sure you are using data after call is completed.

Subscribe has 3 parameters/sections.

1. Data which is returned,
2. Error if any returned,
3. Call is completed section

   ```
    loadBookingFullRowDataRequest(rowId: number) {
   this.bookingFullRowData[rowId] = [];
   this.bookingService.getAllBookingData().subscribe(res => {
     this.bookingFullRowData = <Booking[]>res[rowId];
     console.log('all booking data: ', this.bookingFullRowData, 'rowId: ', rowId);
     for (const item of this.bookingFullRowData) {
       const itemId = `${item['title']}-rowid-${item['rowid']}-proj-${item['proj']}`;
       this.bookingsForm.addControl(itemId, new FormControl(
         `${item['content']}`
       ));
     }
   }, ()=> {console.log(error)}, // error
   ```

   ()=> // call is completed here you can do aftercall tasks  {
       console.log('the whole loaded dta:', this.bookingFullRowData, 'row: ', this.currentRow); this.modalService.createModal('#bookings-form', null, this.dialogOptions)} );   }